# Programs sometimes open on the wrong monitor

Tags: screen, monitor

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04LTS 32bit version with 2 screens. 
Graphic card is the Nvidia Geforce 9500GT.
One screen is the main monitor, where the other is connected to my beamer for the home cinema.

I'm using the Kodi media center, and have it set up to start fullscreen on the beamer, wich works perfectly.

BUT...

Sometimes when i'm using the computer normally, and i open a program, that program opens on the beamer output instead of the normal monitor. 
So i'd have to specially turn on my beamer, wait till it's warmed up, and then i can drag the program to the correct screen. (not really good for the lamp to just turn it on for like 5 minutes or so.)

So, is there an option to force a program to start on the main monitor? 
If not, is there an option to move the program from display 2, to display 1 with a key combination? so i don't have to specially turn on the beamer for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: usually, in such, case I right click on window name in task manager and select move, then move mouse right (or left) while cursor not appear on screen, then i click mouse button, this ugly but should save your lamps :)  Would to see good answer too

Comment: If the 2nd monitor is off why are you still in multi-monitor mode?

Comment: @glenn jackman because there is no way to detect if second display off

Comment: Thanks ZB. That's a good enough solution. I used to find a button to mark your answer as accepted, but i find this site itself very difficult to work with. So can't mark your answer as accepted, but thanks zb! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Funny that i can write an answer to my own question (even though i'm logged in) but wanted to say that zb's solution is good enough to do the trick :-)
Thanks

edit:
And now it seems i can mark my own answer as "accepted as answer" 
i really don't understand this website at all. Sorry.. total newbie here